# combine two OCG filters in Openlayers

Tags: javascript, filter, openlayers

i need to combine two OCG filters. each one works separably but if i combine them using Filter.Logical.OR, the first one works only.

```
var c_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({ 
type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR, 
filters: [ 
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({ 
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO, 
    matchCase:false, 
    property: 'id', 
    value:(document.getElementById("Text")).value     
    }),   
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({ 
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE, 
    matchCase:false, 
    property: 'name', 
    value: "*" +(document.getElementById("Text")).value + "*"   
    }),   
    ] 
});
```

i use openlayers 2.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing comma(,) after second filter, it shouldn't be there.

If that doesn't help I would try to create filters separately and add them to "or"-filter:

```
orFilter.filters.push(equalToFilter);
orFilter.filters.push(likeFilter);
```

Comment: i tried your suggestion, still, the equalToFilter works fine. but the likeFilter i got the error: 
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "test name" 
i don't understand why it should be integer !! 
and if i try likeFilter alone, it works fine !

Comment: Is your filter works if try to specify values of "value" properties of each filter manually?

Comment: No, it always displays the value of the first filter.